# Does QT have reflections for C++?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qt6

I want to create a SQL table in QT C++. So I have made this code.

And it is going to create a database for me, where the first argument `tableName` is the name of the table I want to create. Then the next argument is quite tricky.

Here, `columns`, specify the column name and it's data type. I think this is a bad way to do. Example

```
 QVector<QPair<QString, QString>> myColumns = new QVector<QPair<QString, QString>>{{"ID", "BIGINT"}, {"logging_id", "INT"}};
```

Because If i have for example like 50 columns. The `myColumns` is going to be very long.
My question if QT C++ have some kind of reflections, so I can:

- Get the name if every field
- Get the data type of every field
- If the field is an array, then I'm going to know how many elements there are inside that array

I was planning to have an entity class where I create a class, and use that class to get the information to create each columns in the database.

```
 void Database::createTable(QString tableName, const QVector<QPair<QString, QString>> columns){

    QSqlQuery query;
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length(); i++){
        /* Get the Qpair values */
        QString columnName = columns.at(i).first;
        QString dataType = columns.at(i).second;
        /* If key is ID, then try to create a new table */
        if(columnName == "ID"){
            query.exec("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "(" + columnName + " " + dataType + " NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)");
            continue;
        }
        /* If not, then try append new columns */
        query.exec("ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " ADD " + columnName + " " + dataType);
    }
}
```

Comment: SQL table with 50 columns?  That sounds like MongoDB?  Is your DB design normalized?

Comment: @zipzit I don't know. I'm using MySQL. It works to have lot of columns. But the C++ code will be quite messy.

Comment: Qt does offer [a form of reflection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html). Not on any arbitrary C++ class member, but on those specifically exposed via `Q_PROPERTY`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If `Qobject` is the way to go. I think I will use that. Do you want to write a answer to this question so I can accept it?